# What's the default proxy settings in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: proxy, environment-variables

Linux newbie here. I tried to set up system proxy by changing environment variables (such as "http_proxy"), but now I no longer need it. The problem is, I forgot what the default (not using any proxy) settings were, and I couldn't find any relevant resources online. Could someone please tell me what I should change it back into?

Comment: I am unsure on "defaults" but suspect you just want to turn it off? Configuration [is multi-stepped](https://medium.com/@krish.raghuram/setting-up-proxy-in-ubuntu-95058da0b2d4) so it really depends on what you did.

Answer (score 0):

To remove proxy settings, you must comment with # the following lines in these files, if they exist:

File: /etc/bash.bashrc

Lines:

```
export http_proxy=http:
export https_proxy=http:
export ftp_proxy=http:
```

File:  /etc/environment

Lines:

```
http_proxy=http:
https_proxy=http:
ftp_proxy=http:
```

File  /etc/apt/apt.conf

Lines:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http:";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http:";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "http:";
```

Comment: I already checked all three files you mentioned -- there's no proxy related settings. I've successfully disabled http_proxy, https_proxy and ftp_proxy. However, "all_proxy" is left no matter what I do. When I use env | grep proxy to check, it still shows "all_proxy=xxx.xxx". I can unset it, but it just works temporarily. I'm looking for a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

It could be hidden in any shell settings file, system: `/etc/environment`,`/etc/environment.d`,`/etc/profile`,... or user: `~/.profile`,...

So, search for it using:

```
sudo grep -ir http_proxy ~/ /etc/
```

Then remove it or comment it using `#` at line beginning.

If it is not there, it could be in Gnome settings.